# Methods to prove axiom independence

Tags: reference-request, big-list

What methods have been used to prove the [independence of axioms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_independence)? For instance, in many abstract algebra books the axiom of choice is stated to be independent of all the other axioms of set theory, but the proof/justification of this often left out.

Comment: Details are very theory-dependent. One general technique of showing that Axiom $A$ is independent of the theory $T$ is to construct a model of $T$ in which $A$ is true, and a model in which $A$ is false.

Comment: As André Nicolas pointed out, the independence of the axiom of choice is difficult. It was an unsolved problem for at least 40 years, and Cohen got a Fields medal for completing a proof of its independence. For more accessible ZF independence proofs, see the following paper (freely available on the internet): Alexander Abian and Samuel Eugene LaMacchia, [*On the consistency and independence of some set-theoretical axioms*](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ndjfl/1093888220), **Notre Dame Journal of Formal Logic** 19 #1 (January 1978), 155-158.